# Create a new file at webcontent or web-inf in a Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {                 

     Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames();

     String fileName=itr.next();
     MultipartFile file = request.getFile(fileName);

     if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                File fileNew=new File(file.getOriginalFilename());


                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileNew));

                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                System.out.println(fileNew.getAbsolutePath());

                return "You successfully uploaded " + fileName + " into " + fileName + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + fileName + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + fileName + " because the file was empty.";
        }


  }
```

File gets created at

```
F:\springsource-tool-suite-2.8.1.RELEASE-e3.7.1-win32\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\
```

To make a long story short, I would like to create a new file at **webcontent** or **WEB-INF**.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

- Can Autowired `ServletContext` in your controller, then get real path from your method

  `@Autowired`
  `ServletContext servletContext;`
- Or as vzamanillo's answer

  `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
File fileNew = new File(request.getSession().
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/"), file.getOriginalFilename());
```

Docs about [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)